# editing scrollTop to use href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have the following code for a certain link on my website to scroll back to the top, but I can't figure out how I can change this to use a specified href value instead of a pixel value. 
Current script:

```
$('.scrollToTop').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
            return false;
        });
```

An example of what I'm trying to do is for a main navigation link to a Contact div to scroll down to the href="#contact".

I've tried setting up if/else statements but to no avail, it could be down to a rough New Years night.

**EDIT**
the hrefs I'm using are unique ids for each div that I want to scroll to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#section-name').offset().top});
```

**EDIT**

I'll further explain the `#section-name` part: it's whatever you want, `id`, `class` you can use `$("a")`, `$("div")`, it's a selector.

So you can add a `class` to your `href` and target that class name if you want.

**UPDATE**

If you want to find the value of the href you choose you can do (I'm assuming `.scrollToTop` is a class name on an `a` tag?):

```
$('.scrollToTop').click(function () {
    var locationName = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(locationName).offset().top});
}):
```

Comment: `#section-name` ? Is that an ID or a `href` ?

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. The OP says 'An example of what I'm trying to do is for a main navigation link to a Contact div to scroll down to the href="#contact".' The #contact isn't a selector , it's just a `href` value

Comment: Will remove the downvote. It's new year after all ;)

Comment: haha well I'm assuming he's referring to the fact that he wants the page to animate down to a specific section on a button click. But he doesn't want to scroll by pixel count, so what I posted allows him to scroll to a section on the page by some kind of element, class name, id, etc. So you add something, same idea as adding an anchor point (`<a name="contact"></a>`) and linking to it with `href="#contact"`. It's the same thing, this just animates the page instead of jumping to the link like normal html. Hope that helps.

Comment: "So you can add a class to your href and target that class name if you want." This is exactly what I was hoping you would say , without which , the answer would be incomplete :-) cheers

Comment: This works perfectly, however could i take in the value of the href as a value and set the `scrollTop:$('#section-name')` to use this value instead of writing this code for each link?

Comment: @MarkLordan sure, ill update my answer above. Also can you check this off?